# Electron and cdn links

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is it possible to use cdn links in renderer? I am using

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nerdamer@0.7.16/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
```

in an standalone index.html and working as intended but when I try to put this in Electron's renderer  I get

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './nerdamer.core.js'
```

Interesting thing is even when I put this file locally, I get the same error.

```
<script src="externalLibs/nerdamer.core.js"></script>
```

Can you provide me some insight on this thank you...

Comment: did you do npm install with it?

Comment: Yes I did but no luck. I am using Webstorm by the way.